# VMware vmrc install on Ubuntu fails

Tags: vmware, tools

I'm trying to install **vmrc** on latest Ubuntu. and the bundle fails
i get issues with he VMware USB-arbitrager. any way to download and install the arbitrator.

```
2019-11-04T14:29:38.533-07:00| usbArb| I125: Log for VMware USB Arbitration Service pid=2084 version=15.5.0 build=build-14461205 option=Release
2019-11-04T14:29:38.533-07:00| usbArb| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.533-07:00| usbArb| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2019-11-04T14:29:38.533-07:00| usbArb| I125: Host is Linux 5.3.0-19-generic Ubuntu 19.10
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: VTHREAD 140261587288896 "usbArb" tid 2084
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/etc/vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/etc/vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /etc/vmware/config. Using default values.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.532-07:00| usbArb| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/config. Using default values.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.675-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- GLOBAL SETTINGS /usr/lib/vmware/settings
2019-11-04T14:29:38.675-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- NON PERSISTENT (null)
2019-11-04T14:29:38.675-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- HOST DEFAULTS /etc/vmware/config
2019-11-04T14:29:38.675-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- SITE DEFAULTS /usr/lib/vmware/config
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: VMware USB Arbitration Service Version 18.7.0
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBGL: USB Sysfs found at /dev/bus/usb
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBArb: Attempting to connect to existing arbitrator on /var/run/vmware/usbarbitrator-socket.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: SOCKET creating new socket, connecting to /var/run/vmware/usbarbitrator-socket
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: SOCKET connect failed, error 2: No such file or directory
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBArb: No other USB arbitrator instance is currently running.
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBArb: listening socket 12 created successfully
2019-11-04T14:29:38.676-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBArb: adding listening socket 12 to poll queue
root@afalk-E7470:/var/log/vmware# ^C
root@afalk-E7470:/var/log/vmware# net start hcmon
```